# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

Estaba mandando un excell por medio de Angular2 y lo estaba recibiendo el SpringBoot, el problema es cuando además del Excell quiero mandar un 2º objecto.
Al mandar el segundo objeto, me salta un error.

Código de Angular donde declaro la clase y el objeto:

```
export class DataUser {
  addData: Date;
  addUser: string;
  dateModification: Date;
  userModification: string;
}
public newParam: DataUser = {
    addData: null,
    addUser: "",
    dateModification: null,
    userModification: ""
}

addExcell() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/gn/insert";
    this.newParam = {
      addData: new Date(),
      addUser: this.cookie.get('user'),
      dateModification: new Date(),
      userModification: this.cookie.get('user')
    }
    this.service.sendFile(url, this.formData, this.newParam).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }

  sendFile(url, myFile, newParam ) {
    return this.http.post(url,   myFile ,  newParam);
  }
```

Después para recogerlo en el SpringBoot->

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insert", headers = "Content-Type= multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public MyMessage insert(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile multipart , @RequestBody DataUser dataUser) {
```

Donde el primer parámetro es el Excell y el segundo el objeto(usuario).

Clase usuario

```
public class DataUser {

    public Date addData;
    public String addUser;
    public Timestamp dateModification;
    public String usermodification;
    public DataUser(Date addData, String addUser, Timestamp dateModification, String usermodification) {
        super();
        this.addData = addData;
        this.addUser = addUser;
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
        this.usermodification = usermodification;
    }
```

Con sus getters y setters, para que correspondan las 2 clases.

Este es el error que sale en el SpringBoot

```
2018-07-17 11:58:30.880  WARN 4092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary2i0ZEb9BQ1SkKbEc;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Error en Angular2

```
http://localhost:8080/gn/insert 415 ()
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/gn/insert", ok: false, …}
error:
{timestamp: 1531825158243, status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type", exception: "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException", message: "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----Web…darypMcoVNA9Ov1DBx7J;charset=UTF-8' not supported", …}
headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message:"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/gn/insert: 415 OK"
name:"HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status:415
statusText:"OK"
url:"http://localhost:8080/gn/insert"
```

Un amigo dice que puede ser que es porque le falten cabeceras en las peticiones o envíos, no sé, yo soy muy nuevo, pero he cogido el error que sale que dice 
Content type 'multipart/form-data y se lo he metido al SpringBoot para que tenga eso de multipar/form y sigue dando el error, así que no sé que cabecera le falta, suponiendo que sea cierto que es cosa de cabeceras.Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacerlo es la siguiente:

En Angular, añade tu formulario al formData donde ya tienes el fichero:

```
this.formData.append('dataUser',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.newParam)],
    {
        type: "application/json"
    })
);
```

En Spring, recibe cada parte así:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> insert(@RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("dataUser") DataUser model){
    // código aquí
}
```

Fíjate que estamos usando `RequestPart` y no `RequestParam` o `RequestBody`

Pregunta similar en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064548/uploading-file-with-other-form-fields-in-angular-2-and-spring-mvc

Comment: Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'uploadFile' is not present

Comment: No encuentra el fichero... ¿has añadido uno?

Comment: por supuesto que sí.

Comment: this.formData.append('dataUser',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.newParam)], newParam es el objeto Usuario , no el excell.

Comment: faltaba añadir una línea de append, para el fichero en tu respuesta, ahora sale otro error --> message: "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of ww…PushbackInputStream@70fbe23f; line: 1, column: 2]

Comment: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of DataUser: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of DataUser: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: le puse el implements Serializable a la clase y tampoco.

Comment: Prueba a crear un constructor vacío a la clase DataUser

Comment: pfff, eres un máquina, muchas gracias !!